# Can't read from serial device in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-requests, pyserial

I'm running a process using python GUI (using Tkinter). The process opens a thread that is supposed to read from a device connected via USB.

code example:

```
self.com = serial.Serial()
x = self.com.read(size)
```

After reading the data, it is sent to a server.

Usually it works fine but sometimes I get an exception when trying to send the request to server:

> if requests.codes.ok != responseObj.status_code: AttributeError:
>   'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'

The problem is that I'm getting a `dict` type instead of `Response` object.

Could this be related to the thread that for some reason can't read the device output.

I tried to simulate the exception but it's hard to reproduce.
Any help with what could be the reason for this failure or ideas on how to reproduce it so I can debug it myself would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you look in the object? Maybe it has some useful information such as an error message.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley. it was very helpful . I found a bug in my code. How can I close this question as it no longer relevant?